# Single word for someone who prefers to work without timelines

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Is there a word for someone who works on a particular task without worrying about the time that he spends on it. Someone with an attitude of "it'll take as much time that it has to take". But he is persistent with the work, but doesn't like the idea of timelines.

Comment: It's someone who *works at their own pace*.

Comment: Does *freelance* count?

Comment: @NVZ It has "free" in it. It should, at least in overtones.

Answer (score 1):

That person sounds very [**lassiez-faire**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laissez%E2%80%93faire)

> a philosophy or practice characterized by a usually deliberate abstention from direction or interference especially with individual freedom of choice and action

or perhaps prefers to work [**unstructured**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unstructured)

> not happening according to a plan : not organized or planned in a formal way

Comment: There is a plan/structure. But no timelines.

Comment: Fair enough. Unstructured is an adjective which you could apply to time. Think of a timeline like a "plan" where you get certain deliverables ready by certain deadlines.

Comment: Unstructured seems too general a word, whereas I am looking for something very specific, it if exists.

Comment: Perhaps, if you want something that serves as an antonym for timeline, you might consider "non-linear" to describe the person/work pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a close adjective.

That someone is **unbound**.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbound)

> not controlled, limited or influenced by something.

Answer (score 1):

The King's carpenter in the English Civil War carved **SAT CITO, SAT BENE** on one of his buildings, "Fast enough is soon enough," a popular [Emblem](http://www.emblems.arts.gla.ac.uk/french/emblem.php?id=FBOb022), at that time.
Such workers are called 'deliberate,'

> **Deliberate**: (adjective) [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deliberate)
>
> 2. Careful and unhurried:
>    *example:* a conscientious and deliberate worker

Answer (score 0):

The person sounds like 'a plodder'

> A person who plods, esp one who works in a slow and persevering but
>   uninspired manner

[free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plodder)